# Secure a Self-Serv Computer ? - Need to Disable IE escape, etc

Tags: javascript, html, windows, web, lockdown

We have developed a "Self Service Till" will allow people to order stuff in store, get a receipt and come and pick up later. It was done in HTML, Javascript, PHP - that's what I know to code.

---

I now need to lock down the computer to only use the Web Browser.
Would like to disable escaping the internet browser? No ALT+F4 or CTRL+ALT+Del.
Any pointers on this would be great, Keywords im using are not bringing up results.

In addition, print from the web without Print Dialogue - Remember this is intranet service not public. Any recommendations much appropriated.

TL;DR - How do I lock down the computer to the web browser only?

Answer (score 0):

You want kiosk mode: [kiosk mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780)

This will open IE in full screen mode.

You will also want to disable alt-f4 to prevent users from leaving kiosk mode via group policy:

start - run - gpedit.msc
User configuration - Administrative Templates - System